# Problems with simple float values

Tags: python, types, floating-point

We have these three values:

x = 7.68

y = 7.775

z = 7.87

It happens that y-x = z-y = 0.095, but Python insists on assigning the following values:

y-x = 0.09500000000000064

z-y = 0.094999999999999975

It is an insignificant difference, but enough to return wrong results, for example:

y-x == z-y returns False, which is not true, the comparison should return True (0.095 == 0.095)

The fact is that those types of results are throwing me a comparison routine and the function returns me wrong results for it.
How could you avoid this, if possible without using "external" typo sympy modules?

Comment: Have you tried using the same number of digits for each number?

Comment: You should use the `Decimal` object in this particular case I believe.

Comment: Number of digits used as shown in x, y, z values.

Comment: Tested with Decimal and don't works, I get strange values.